# Capture API from CosmicMind-Material: Camera preview not correct

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, cosmicmind

When CaptureController is being push using navigation controller, camera preview is always portrait. When going to landscape it won't reflect the camera preview. But when it's just a "self.present" it's okay like the sample project. How can I manipulate when orientation is landscape and the camera preview is also landscape. Captured image have correct orientation, just the camera preview.

Lanscape but the camera preview orientaion is portait - Sample image attached:
[link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgpq3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! This line fix the issue:

```
(capture.preview.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection.videoOrientation = videoOrientation
```

Just put it in the delegate function

```
func capture(capture: Capture, didChangeFrom previousVideoOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation, to videoOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation)
```